# Why chmod 777 is not secure?

Tags: apache, security, server

> chmod 777 file    change the permissions of the file file to read, write,
>   and execute for all.

Ok, so the file can be manipulated in any way by any script on the server. But why is this not secure?

If you already have a script there, than the person who uploaded it has access to your server anyway... So what's the catch here?

Comment: Good question. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338641/in-a-php-apache-linux-context-why-exactly-is-chmod-777-dangerous and http://serverfault.com/questions/265205/why-is-it-so-important-to-remove-777-permissions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One reason is that it's easier to gain **user** access to a linux server than it is to gain **root** or the specific user that's allowed to access the script. If you set the permissions so anyone can access/modify/delete all important scripts, then you're removing a layer of security that user based permissions provide. If someone fumbles across a **user** account then they can take down your server. The best security is built in layers.

Maybe your question is based on how FTP accounts work. If you have a full ftp access account to a server, then you can do anything you want to the available files regardless of their permission. That's an insecurity in allowing full FTP access to a server.

This isn't limited to linux servers, just using them as an example.